# What is the difference between dilation and padding?

Tags: image-processing, padding, dilation

I am trying to understand the basic difference between padding and dilation.

As I understand, padding is the resulting creation of new 0 valued cells (? or matrix positions) at the ends of the image matrix upon convolution by a filter.

Dilation, too, changes the ends of an image, given a filter. Is there a particular difference between the two?

Thanks

Comment: The dilation is a filter (a non-linear filter, but still it filters the image). Dilation doesn't add new values to the image, no filtering does. But we often pad the image before filtering, so that the filter never extends outside the image domain when applied. It is normal to remove the padded regions after the filter has been applied, such that the filtered image is of the same size as the input image.

Comment: Padding adds new rows/columns to the image. Dilation is a max filter. Some implementations of dilation may pad the image before filtering. If you have a specific language or library you're using, it might be helpful to create examples of each and see what they do.

Comment: Right. I follow the points about padding clearly, however, the idea of dilation and its use and the difference between the two is still quite not clear. To elaborate, dilation appears in the context of morphological image processing in the Digital Image Processing book by Gonzalez and Wood which seems to be different from convolution. I'm not particularly looking for a technical explanation. What does dilating an image mean? Thanks.

Comment: Think of a black background with white objects/shapes on it. Dilation makes the white shapes bigger. Erosion makes them smaller.

Comment: As @CrisLuengo said, dilation is a non-linear filter, so it is not strictly a convolution. Rather than multiplying the elements of the array by the kernel elements and summing to get the filtered value, dilation simply takes the maximum of the image elements within the window.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things greatly. I understand the first point as well now. Regards.